# Transformer la phrase en discours indirect

Tags: grammaire, discours-indirect

Comment transformer la phrase suivante en discours indirect ?

> Il m'a dit: "J'ai rencontré Pierre il y a quelques années."

Je dirais :

> Il m'a dit qu'il avait rencontré Pierre quelques années auparavant.

Comment: change *ans* pour **années**  ( dans les deux cas ) et c'est tout bon!

Comment: @aCOSwt Est-ce qu'il faut toujours employer "années" avec "il y a" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le principe appliqué dans la transformation est valide et probablement le plus courant. Cependant, il en existe un autre ; appliqué à la présente phrase, il donne ceci :

> « Il m'a dit avoir rencontré Pierre quelques années auparavant. » ;

au lieu d'une subordonnée conjonctive avec « que » on utilise une subordonnée infinitive.

**Note** Le complément de temps peut se placer d'abord dans la proposition subordonnée conjonctive; le style pourrait être considéré comme plus littéraire, bien que toujours convenable dans la langue parlée (c'est à dire pas extravagant).

- Il m'a dit que quelques années auparavant il avait rencontré Pierre.